# The $k$th move of the Tower of Hanoi

Tags: puzzle, recursion

> In the tower of Hanoi $x,y,z$ are the positions and we are to move 10 disks from $x$ to $y$. What are the 128th and 768th moves?
>
> (A) $x\to y$ and $x\to z$
>
> (B) $x\to z$ and $z\to x$
>
> (C) $x\to z$ and $z\to y$
>
> (D) $x\to y$ and $z\to y$

I know the total number of moves is $2^{10}-1=1023$. For move 128 I did $128\bmod3=2$, which gave me nothing at all… please help me out!

Comment: What to you call a move ? I see two possibilities.

Comment: find at $128^{th} and 768^{th} $ moves ,what will be its movement!

Comment: @YvesDaoust what are they?

Comment: Hint: for $n$ disks, you need to shift $n-1$ disks and stack them up on some pole in order to shift the $n$th disk. Now, since your moves are just repeating this pattern, you can compute: to move 2 disks, how many moves must i make? 3 disks? 4 disks? The number of moves needed to move $k$ disks to a (single) new pole is well-known, so use this to determine your moves. For example, $128 = 2^7$. With 127 moves, how many disks can be moved? With 128?

Comment: concluding your hint,i got $\Rightarrow$ for n disk ,we follow $\Rightarrow$ move $\left(n-1\right)$ disk to $z$ ,  $n^{th}$ disk to y and then $\left(n-1\right)$ disk again from $z$ to $y$,,with 128 moves ...7 disk have been moved...$2^{n}-1=128$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try listing out the moves for one, two and three discs:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
XY
xz XY zy
xy xz yz XY zx zy xy
```

There is a pattern here that allows us to get the sequence of moves for the next number of discs:

1. We copy the whole sequence for the previous number of discs, but replace `y` with `z` and vice versa.
2. We append `xy`.
3. We append the previous sequence again, but replace `x` with `z` and vice versa.

This allows us to find the source and destination pegs of the $k$th move of the $n$-disc sequence:

1. Initialise the source and destination pegs as `x` and `y` respectively. Write out $k$ as an $n$-bit binary word (zero-padded on the left) and place a pointer on the least significant `1`.
2. Stop and return the source and destination pegs if the pointer is on the most significant bit. Otherwise, move the pointer one place left. If it lands on a `0`, replace `y` with `z` and vice versa; if it lands on a `1`, replace `x` with `z` and vice versa. Repeat step 2.

---

Here, $n=10$, so the set-ups for finding the 128th and 768th moves are as follows:

```
0010000000 = 128
  ^ xy
 ^ xz
^ xy -> 128th move is x -> y
1100000000 = 768
 ^ xy
^ zy -> 768th move is z -> y
```

Hence the correct answer is (d).

By the way, here's the algorithm for the 72nd move:

```
0001001000 = 72
   |  ^ xy
   | ^ xz
   |^ xy
   ^ zy
  ^ yz
 ^ zy
^ yz -> 72nd move is y -> z
```

Comment: Find for $72^{nd}$ move,bit will be 0001001000,starting pointer  at $4^{th}$ position from lsb,we have $x \rightarrow y$ after your algo terminates i am left out with  $z \rightarrow z$!!!!!please check it once @parcly

Comment: @laura You should be left with $z\to x$. When you have something like $x\to z$ and the rule calls for swapping x with z and vice versa, the result is $z\to x$ and not $z\to z$ - _every_ $x$ and $z$ is affected.

Comment: okk @parcly i done as you said ...got $z \rightarrow x $ at the end....should be  $y \rightarrow z $ for $72^{nd} $ moves ...see this http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/TowerofHanoi.html  take moveTower(10,"A","B","C")

Comment: @laura OK, I got that wrong... Read my algorithm carefully. On 0 replace y with z and vice versa, on 1 replace x with z and vice versa. You should get $y\to z$.

Comment: it would be better if you would provide me sequence for $72 ^{nd}$ moves ,,,$0001001000$ starting with $x \rightarrow y$ $\Rightarrow$ $x \rightarrow z$ $\Rightarrow$ $x \rightarrow y$ $\Rightarrow$ $z \rightarrow y$ $\Rightarrow$ i am stuck over here

Comment: @laura In the answer now.

Comment: thankx @parcly ...i guess none algo can be as best as this to find this solution :)